# Resizing iOS Google map incurs significant performance hit when map view reaches the size of the Google logo

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am posting this message as it appears to be the recommended way to communicate with the maps team.

We have observed a significant performance hit (e.g 60FPS to 40FPS) when resizing a map on iOS.

The performance hit is incurred at the point the map reaches the same height size of the 'Google' logo, from here a significant drop in FPS is observed.

Significantly we notice that on Android when we perform the same step the Google logo scales proportionally to the size of the map view. No performance hit is observed on Android.

On iOS, the logo is **not** resized as the view changes size - we think this is related to the bug in some manner.

Using the instruments profiler, we note that mach_msg_trap appears to significantly increase in use when the jitter occurs, with suspect methods within that call chain being `[IOSurface initWithProperties]`, `create_iosurface_with_pixel_format()` and `allocate_buffer()`

In our particular circumstance, for reasons that are irrelevant to the bug: we have a scrolling view, as the view is scrolled and the map gets pushed off the screen we want to shrink the map to its currently visible on screen size.

Can someone from the maps team please investigate?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you are doing is changing the `frame` of the map's `UIView`, right?

There is a different way to do this. Set the `GMSMapView` frame so it covers the whole superview and change the padding instead using Google Maps provided property `padding`:
[Google Maps : Map padding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map#map_padding)

Example:

```
let mapInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 300.0)
mapView.padding = mapInsets
```